# FluentValidation on JObject property to validate MustBeSafeJson()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

The JObject property ***MyCustomField*** will have json data. I need to validate using **MustBeSafeJson()** and **MaximumLength(500)**. I'm not sure what is the right syntax. I tried the following, but it throws the same error for any syntax.
This is a ASP.Net Core Web Api application.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public JObject MyCustomField { get; set; }
}


RuleFor(x => x.MyCustomField).  //does not show any of the validation choices like MustBeSafeJson()
```

Tried

```
RuleFor(x => x.MyCustomField.ToSerializedString()).MustBeSafeJson();
RuleFor(x => x.MyCustomField.ToString()).MustBeSafeJson();
```

Error Message

```
Error
    "errorModel:"{
        "value":{
            "":[
                "'' cannot contain certain symbol characters."
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can not you deserialize JObject outside Validator and then pass the string for validating? If not, you can use Must() method to validate and inside this you must deserialide you JObject and then run you validation rules

Comment: If not clear I can create an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not clearly understand what `MustBeSafeJson()` is supposed to do. But you can write your own validation on `JObject` with the below code.

```
 public MyClass_Validation()
 {
     RuleFor(x => x.MyCustomField).Must(x => SAFE_JSON(x, 500));
 }


 private bool SAFE_JSON(JObject arg,int maxSize = 1024)
 {
     ///ValidationLogic goes here      
 }
```

Comment: I have a method "bool JsonValidator.IsSafeText(JObject arg, int maxSize = 1024)" I'm trying to do like your example RuleFor(x => x.MyCustomField).Must(JsonValidator.IsSafeText); It throws "Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Func<JObject,bool>'

Answer (score 0):

How i told you in comments, you should pass a json string to a validator or serialize it inside that, follow an full example:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass
        {
            MyCustomField = new JObject
            {
                { "FieldA", "A" },
                { "FieldB", "B" }
            }
        };
        var result = new Validator().Validate(myClass);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public JObject MyCustomField { get; set; }
}

public class Validator : AbstractValidator<MyClass>
{
    public Validator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.MyCustomField).Must(MustBeSafeJson);
    }

    private bool MustBeSafeJson(JObject arg)
    {
        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arg);
        return RunValidatingRules(jsonString);
    }

    private bool RunValidatingRules(string jsonString)
    {
        //execute your rules
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To see your validating results, just inspect the Errors property `result.Errors`. If `result.IsValid`returns false, there will be something